# How do I stop adverts being shown on a WordPress hosted blog?

Tags: wordpress, ads

I think WordPress shows adverts on blogs/webpages they host.

Can I disable the adverts and what does it cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://en.support.wordpress.com/no-ads/  for details of how to turn off adverts, this costs $29.97 per year.

Comment: If I download the wordpress package and host it in a local server, will I still get adverts?